# Upgraded to 8.0.0 (Oreo) and Notification Vibrations Won't Stop

Tags: notifications, vibration, 8.0-oreo

I didn't change any settings between 7 and 8, but suddenly I'm getting overwhelmed with my phone vibrating for every single notification. I still want to get my notifications (of which there are many) but I can't stand having my phone vibrate nonstop.

The way it used to work (for me) was that my first Gmail notification would vibrate; but then subsequent emails wouldn't trigger the vibration until I had cleared out all of the old notifications. Also, none of my Twitter accounts ever made any vibrations, but now they are all making them, for every single tweet. It's insane.

I've searched around in the App menues, in the phone settings, and online, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to turn off vibrations (but still get notifications.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I ran a google search, and came across this thread. I hope it helps for you too!

https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-pixel-pixel-xl/828108-turning-off-vibration-oreo.html

(One mentioned in that thread, that Twitter doesn't have a setting to shut it off. I don't have Twitter installed, so I can't verify) I did go into all of my notifications (each and every one) and had to turn off the vibrate. It is very tedious, but hopefully helps you too.

UPDATE: Just in case that thread mentioned above, disappears. Here is the quote from the user on how to disable the vibration on each notification

"Super annoying thing Oreo started, happened to me too. For some reason Google thought this was a good idea?!

Go into settings, apps and notifications, app info, messages, app notifications (again sheesh) and then you have to go into each and every category and uncheck vibrate. Thanks Google"

Answer (score 0):

I have a soloution for you.But first you should backup important messages and then 
you can(should) delete all of messages.From hereafter every messages comes without
vibration.

Comment: Can you explain your answer or give some reference or details some person experience to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly easier on a Samsung running Oreo (the S9 at least anyway, which is the only one officially carrying it to date AFAIK).
I primarily dug into this as I was getting notifications vibrating on Twitter left right and centre.

To get to the settings: when you get a notification, you can either swipe slightly right on it, and tap the gear icon, or alternatively at the bottom of the drop-down tap on Notification settings, then once in that, as DarkWolfNine states above, you have to tap on the name of each app, and within that you can either completely switch off each 'category' of notifications, or you can tap on its name to change its settings, including vibrate.
And yes, you have to go into every single category and turn it off, which on Twitter for one, is very tedious! (I had 9 categories, others may have more). And then every other app has its own category(s).

I think this is a real dropped ball on Google's part, since there seems to be no global settings for this or anything.